# React: How to trigger forceUpdate/render of component as function (not class)?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

Here is example very similar to the one documented in [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/rendering-elements.html#updating-the-rendered-element). Let's say we have a Clock component, which is presented as function (not class):

```
//Clock.jsx
function Clock(props) {

  setInterval(()=>{
     // ??? how to trigger forceUpdate/render here???
  }, 1000);


  return (
    <div>
      <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Clock;
```

And then let's say some parent component that import this file:

```
//index.jsx
import Clock from 'Clock'

..
render(){ return (
  <div>
     <Clock />
  </div>);
}
..
```

Is there any way to do it without making Clock a class?

Comment: You could argue that the fact that the component maintains a timer makes the component stateful, and therefore should be a class (with which this would be trivial).

Answer (score 0):

You could move your `setInterval` into the parent class, and pass down the value you want the Clock component to render as a prop to the Clock.

I would set up your `setInterval` in a `componentDidMount` inside the parent class, and have the callback be a `getCurrentTime` function which just `return new Date().toLocaleTimeString()`.  That will trigger the render which will update the clock's props.

This would make the Clock component appropriately a dumb component because it is only displaying information passed to it by a smart component.

Comment: Thanks for response, but `setInterval` is a private encapsulated Clock's logic, I don't want to parent to know all private implementation details of any of its children

Comment: If that's the case you'll need to make the Clock a class to maintain it's own state.  The point of presentational components as you currently have Clock is that they maintain no state and only present what they are given by the parent.  Hope that helps!